# Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Defining a hash with symbol keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Regarding the exercises in Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial in lesson 4.3.3 (Hashes & Symbols):

"Define a hash with symbol keys corresponding to name, email, and a “password digest”, and values equal to your name, your email address, and a random string of 16 lower-case letters."

I am hoping to get some input and/or alternative & 'better' solutions to this (or at least some criticism regarding my solution).

```
def my_hash
  a = ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0..15].join
  b = { name: "John", email: "johndoe@gmail.com", password: a }
  return b
end

puts my_hash
```

(Yes I realize this is a very simple exercise and apologize if it has been asked before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many 2 improvements could be made:

1. Use [`Array#sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) to get random letters (it has an advantage: the letter might in fact repeat in the password, while `shuffle[0..15]` will return 16 *distinct* letters);
2. Avoid redundant local variables and especially `return`.

Here you go:

```
def my_hash
  {
    name: "John",
    email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
    password: ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(16).join
  }
end

puts my_hash
```

---

*Bonus:*

I accidentaly found the third glitch in the original code. It should probably be:

```
def my_hash
  {
    name: "Brandon",
    email: "brandon.elder@gmail.com",
    password: ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(16).join
  }
end
```

:)

Comment: That's cool.  I havn't come across the `Enumerable#sample` yet but I can see the advantage there.  Thanks!  Also, wondering if it is just a matter of taste or best practice not to have all of the key/value pairs on a single line?

Comment: Regarding single line: here it’s mostly a matter of respecting those reading from smartphones and having not-so-wide screens. AFAIR, [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) has a default rule to have lines not wider than 80 characters. But it’s definitely up to code owner/team to set up such rules.

Comment: ok..that's good to know.  I have used rubocop but wasn't aware of that rule.  Very helpful.  lol... And you're right about that glitch.

Comment: There are also arguments that it makes changes easier to track, for example using a `diff` on a git change. It isolates the logical components so you see exactly what has changed more easily (e.g. if the code for the password changed).

Comment: @DavidAldridge well, all modern `git diff` pagers do support highlighting changes _inside_ lines, but yes, I agree, tracking changes matters here.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Ahh..ok...I can also see the benefit of this example for tracking changes & would definitely prefer this.  Thank you.